# Turris.omnia w/ Time Capsule via WiFi

Tags: network, wifi, time-capsule, airport

I have a Time Capsule which I want to connect via Ethernet directly to a [Turris Omnia](https://www.turris.cz/en/omnia/). Better to say it is already connected.

My MacBook is connected via my WiFi which is bridged w/ the LAN.

If I want to look up on the settings via Foris (a simple web interface for the Turris Omnia router) I can’t see it's connected there. I also can’t see it via its AirPort utility.

I set the ports on the firewall for this bridged network (LAN and WiFis - 2.4 Ghz + 5 Ghz).

Does any has an idea to get the Time Capsule connectable via WiFi from the LAN port?

Comment: The question is rather unclear. "my WiFi" is no useful description for a setup providing at least two different WiFi access points (Time Capsule & Turris Omnia). And: yes, you normally can access a TimeCapsule (attached via Ethernet to the Turris Omnia) via Turris Omnia's WiFi - if you didn't configure faulty firewall (bridgewalling?) settings or faulty IP settings on the TC.

Comment: at the timecapsule i disabled wifi.